# How set max / min value type Datetime in Highchart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I currently have this code snippet:

```
function createChartByDay(id, title, subtitle, lineTitle, xTitle, xyData){
    Highcharts.chart((id ? id : 'grafic-container'), {
        chart: {
            type: 'spline'
        },
        title: {
            text: (title ? title : '')
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: (subtitle ? subtitle : '')
        },

        xAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Horas'
            },
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats:{
                day:"%H",
                month:"%m",
                year:"%d/%m/%Y"
            }
            tickInterval: 3600 * 1000, // Establece el intervalo es decir una hora.
            labels: {step: 1} // Establece los labels cada cuanto saltos se mostraran.
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Visitas'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Nro Visitas',
            data: xyData,
        }],
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
            pointFormat: '{point.x:%d/%m/%Y - %H:%M}: {point.y} visitas'
        },
    });
}
```

And the result is the following:

[image]

The problem is that there is a superposition of labels at the bottom, how could you solve it? Try setting min and max but the Datetime format is confusing.
Thanks since now.

Comment: can you explain what you don't like a little more? What do you mean there is a superposition of labels at the bottom?

Comment: The label overlap is 17:08 with 00:00

Comment: @JuanjooTocino I'd suggest read this guide: 

[**`xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats`**](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats).